# Formik FieldArray

Tags: reactjs, formik

How do I access the Formik FieldArray arrayHelpers in my child component ProjectsTable?

```js
 <form>
      <FieldArray name="projects"
         render={arrayHelpers => (<ProjectsTable {...this.props}/>)}
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was as simple as this:

```
 <ProjectsTable arrayHelpers={arrayHelpers} {...otherprops} />
```